# Nodemailer - Error: Invalid greeting. response=* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT ID CHILDREN NAMESPACE IDLE UIDPLUS STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN]

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo tras recibir el formulario de contacto pero me da un error estoy usando node js y el modulo nodemailer y segun yo todo debería estar bien pero me da un error.

Este es el error de consola:
[image: Este es el error de consola]

Código JS:

```
    let { name, lastname, email, quest } = req.body;
    contentHTML = `
        <h1>User Information</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Username: ${name}</li>
            <li>User lastname: ${lastname}</li>
            <li>User correo: ${email}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>${quest}</p>
    `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'imap.secureserver.net',
        port: 143,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: config.email,
            pass: config.pass
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
    await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `"Team" <${config.email}>`, 
        to: `${email}`,
        subject: 'Solicitud',
        html: contentHTML,
        text: "is a test"
    })
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! Por consideración a los viejunos como yo, procura siempre compartir trazas de error y código, como texto y no como imagen. Estoy con cara de meme intentando leer lo que pusiste en la imagen de la pregunta. :)

Comment: Lo otro: por favor añade el código que está generando este error, también como texto. Sin incluir contraseñas reales, etc. Tiene toda la pinta de un error en los parámetros de configuración del envío (parece que el servidor espera que uses STARTTLS)

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. Estás usando el puerto 143, que normalmente está asociado a IMAP (que es para recibir y leer emails, como POP). ¿Seguro que tu servicio de envío (SMTP) está en este puerto?
2. Estás usando la opción `secure:false`. ¿Revisaste la documentación del proveedor del servicio de email? De acuerdo a lo que indica el mensaje que muestras en el título, el servidor mismo está anunciando que puede usar STARTTLS. Revisa las [TLS options](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/) en la documentación y usa secure:true para que funcione tu tls-->rejectUnauthorized (con secure:false, creo que eso no tiene ningún efecto)
3. Puedes usar `debug:true` y `logger:true` como nodos bajo `createTransport` para que te muestre todo el intercambio de mensajes con el servidor de envío de emails.

Comment: Si mi probador es godaddy

Comment: Servidor y puertos IMAP

Servidor IMAP entrante: imap.secureserver.net
Puerto SSL: 993
Puerto: 143
Servidor y puertos POP3

Servidor entrante (POP3): pop.secureserver.net
Puerto SSL: 995
Puerto: 110
Servidor y puertos salientes

Servidor saliente (SMTP): smtpout.secureserver.net
Puerto SSL: 465 o 587
Puertos: 80, 3535 o 25

Comment: cual debería usar

Comment: @NewOw3n IMAP y POP son pa leer, SMTP es para enviar, usa puerto y configuración recomendada para SMTP.